# how to limit array's type in specific order in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, definitions

how to limit array's type in specific order in typescript instead of defining paradigm.

that means, in ts, we just declare a array definition like:

`const arr:Array<any> = []`

I want get a specific order in definition array,like:

`const arr = ['string', 0, ...];`

value can only be string tyoe at position 0, and can only be number type at position 1...

thanks

Comment: The arrays at Typescript are homogenous, so what you say can not be done. You can use an object for this purpose.

Comment: I refered to prosemirror-model's definition, it used like this, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to limit the size to 2 elements you can achieve this with a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

```
const myTuple: [string, number] = ['test', 3]
```

or extracted the tuple type definition into a type

```
type myTupleType = [string, number]
const myTuple2: myTupleType = ['test', 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with intersection type:

```
type OrderedArray<T> = Array<T> & {
    0?: string;
    1?: number;
}

const arr: OrderedArray<any> = ['string', 0, ...];
```